# Cannot remotely connect to mysql server in a container

Tags: mysql, docker

I've set up standard mysql container with one user. Container resides on my server. I try to connect to this server from my laptop. Connection works via MySql-workbench. But connection via this command:

`mysql -u user -h <my-server-ip> -p`

gives me following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'<my_laptops_ip>' (using password: YES)`

I've manually connected to this container, connected to mysql via root, and created new account like so:

```
CREATE USER prodigy@'%' identified BY "passwd";
CREATE USER prodigy@'<my_laptops_ip>' IDENTIFIED BY "passwd";

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'prodigy'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'prodigy'@'%';
```

Sadly still the same error when trying to connect.
I've made sure i type correct password.
Where can I go from here to find answer?

mysql.user table for user i'm trying to connect:

```
             Select_priv: Y
             Insert_priv: Y
             Update_priv: Y
             Delete_priv: Y
             Create_priv: Y
               Drop_priv: Y
             Reload_priv: Y
           Shutdown_priv: Y
            Process_priv: Y
               File_priv: Y
              Grant_priv: N
         References_priv: Y
              Index_priv: Y
              Alter_priv: Y
            Show_db_priv: Y
              Super_priv: Y
   Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
        Lock_tables_priv: Y
            Execute_priv: Y
         Repl_slave_priv: Y
        Repl_client_priv: Y
        Create_view_priv: Y
          Show_view_priv: Y
     Create_routine_priv: Y
      Alter_routine_priv: Y
        Create_user_priv: Y
              Event_priv: Y
            Trigger_priv: Y
  Create_tablespace_priv: Y
                ssl_type: 
              ssl_cipher: 
             x509_issuer: 
            x509_subject: 
           max_questions: 0
             max_updates: 0
         max_connections: 0
    max_user_connections: 100
                  plugin: caching_sha2_password
ofsHs4*.U2TDbbZEoghVM2ots1dgBYPr5mCsv2mTBXNDwwaEJxA.
        password_expired: N
   password_last_changed: 2019-08-09 16:24:06
       password_lifetime: NULL
          account_locked: N
        Create_role_priv: Y
          Drop_role_priv: Y
  Password_reuse_history: NULL
     Password_reuse_time: NULL
Password_require_current: NULL
         User_attributes: NULL
```

Comment: Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

Comment: No I did not sir, than you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about 'user'@'my_laptops_ip' connection? But you creating a 'prodigy' user.

Comment: First time i tried  'user'@'my_laptops_ip' because user was created with docker run command. Ten i manually created new user, and tried to connect via  'prodigy'@'my_laptops_ip'.

Comment: Unfortunately no :/

Comment: I've added list of values from mysql.user table, maybe it will help as i'm not sure which are responsible for remote connection.

Comment: The most of users using 'password' in a single quote. Maybe this is causing the problem. Some kind of magic.